IAM User with Predefined Role in PostgreSQL not functioning
After struggling with how to grant an IAM service account read/write permissions on my AlloyDB primary instance, Jack Wotherspoon responded to my inquiry on a GitHub issue. I realized that I can grant the IAM service account the predefined role from PostgreSQL using Terraform.
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/alloydb-python-connector/issues/266
Having passed that step, I am now facing another problem. I want to grant the IAM service account the CREATE DB and CREATE ROLE permissions, which will be used by the App teams to create their objects (I am from the architecture team). I tested different roles, and there are two that meet my requirements: alloydbagent and alloydbimportexport.

I tried granting the alloydbagent role using Terraform but encountered an error.
Error: Error updating User "projects/sbx-200827-data/locations/us-east1/clusters/sbx-200827-data-dave-cluster/users/sa-sbx-200827-data@sbx-200827-data.iam": googleapi: Error 400: invalid roles: role alloydbagent is forbidden
Details:
[
  {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.RequestInfo",
    "requestId": "7f620fb22bf11fb7"
  }
]

  with module.gcp_alloydb.google_alloydb_user.iac_sa_user,
  on ..\..\..\main.tf line 345, in resource "google_alloydb_user" "iac_sa_user":
 345: resource "google_alloydb_user" "iac_sa_user" {

Then I tested the alloydbimportexport role, and it worked. However, when I connected with the IAM user using psql or pgAdmin and tried to create a database or a role, I received an error message about a lack of permissions.

The only workaround I found to create a database is to use the SET ROLE command before the CREATE DATABASE statement. If I do this, it works fine:

While this method works, I am not satisfied with the database owner being the alloydbimportexport role.

My question is: Is there a way to connect directly using the IAM user to PostgreSQL and run a CREATE DATABASE or CREATE ROLE command without using the SET ROLE command? Any suggestions or ideas?

Looking at the Alloydb gcp documentation https://cloud.google.com/alloydb/docs/reference/iam-roles-permissions it seems that the create permissions are only provided at admin level. You might need to check in to create a custom role for your setup

Thanks @Mehul and do you know how to create a custom role for AlloyDB? I didn't find documentation about that.
